# iOS failing share on Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Client requirements are I have to share Image with Description, but as per current Facebook policies I can't share image with description so I am using `FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject`.

Following is my code:

```
  let ph = FBSDKSharePhoto(image: UIImage(named:"testimage"), userGenerated: true)
        
        //These properties you will get via the Get Code menu in facebook app dashboard (where you set up your Action, Object and Custom Story)
        let properties: [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["og:type": "xxxx:quote", "og:title": "xxxx", "og:description": "Thank you  ds sds dsd sd d ds لت"]
        
        //Create the Open Graph object
        let object: FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject(properties: properties)
        
        //Create the action itself
        let action: FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction()
        
        //This comes from the same Get Code menu, but when you select to get the code for the action
        action.actionType = "xxxx:share"
        action.setObject(object, forKey: "xxxx:quote")
        
        //Set the image as an Array, as here you can actually post more than one image
        action.setArray([ph], forKey: "image")
        
        //Create the content and add the action to it
        let content: FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()
        content.action = action
        content.previewPropertyName = "xxxx:quote"
        
        //Execute the Share Dialog
        FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: self)
```

When I am trying to publish I am getting following error

```
  Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=102 "(null)" UserInfo={error_reason=The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBAPIErrorDomain error 2500.), error_description=An error occurred during publishing., app_id=3313803xxxxxxx, error_code=102}
```

I tried to submit app for review on Facebook they said following

> Your app is using the Share plugin to share content to Facebook, so you don't need to submit for review. Publish_actions is only for posting through the Graph API. See our sharing docs for more info on plugins.

How I can accomplish the requirements of posting Image and Text?

Comment: Make your AppId public on Facebook console.. Otherwise it is in developer mode, and only the Facebook account associated with the AppId can be used for testing. Also, FacebookAPI has a "Title" parameter when sharing an image. You can actually put text there and it will share with a description. I'm not sure why this is in their policy if the API has it.. "Hey we created this API with these parameters, don't use it".. Doesn't sound right.

Comment: App is live and its not in developer mode

Comment: Have you turn on "User Generated Images" for that action type ?  @Ali

Comment: i did not turn on any where @maddy